# How to handle update logic in server side when using sveltekit?

Tags: typescript, access-token, patch, sveltekit, cookie-httponly

I'm using a sveltekit.
What I want is to update the input data.
The update itself is simple, but there is a problem, which is that i need to send an accessToken in a header to send an update API request right away.
However, this token is currently contained in a cookie that is processed as httpOnly:true.
So I can't import that cookie into JavaScript, so I think I need to process the update logic on the server side.

I tried to solve it through the action function on the server side, but I am experiencing the following problems.

1. The input data I wrote is being initialized when I press the correction button.
2. I don't know if it's because of the initialization of the input value, but the action function is not getting the value I entered.

Below is the code I wrote.

```
// +page.svelte
<form action="?/updateUser" method="post" use:enhance>
    <div class="mb-6">
        <Label for="email-input" class="block mb-2">email</Label>
        <div class="flex gap-4 w-full">
            <Input id="email-input" size="lg" placeholder="email" bind:value={_email} />
            <Button type="submit" class="w-fit whitespace-nowrap text-sm" disabled={!isEmailChanged}
                >Edit</Button
            >
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
// +page.server.ts
export const actions: Actions = {
    updateUser: async ({ cookies, request }) => {
        const data = await request.formData();

        const email = data.get('email-input') as string;
        console.log({ email });

        // throw redirect(303, '/protected?page=1');
    }
};
```

Any advice is welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand what you mean in your first point, but the data is probably not being sent because form data requires the inputs to have a `name` attribute, `id` is irrelevant. So unless the `Input` component internally sets it, nothing will be sent.

Comment: Thank you for answering. After adding name property the data is sent. 
But if i click the button the input data is empty in the input filed. 
Is this cause by form submit default action? 
It seems like refresh

Comment: `enhance` will reset the form on submission and invalidate the `data`, if you have a `load` function that returns the current e-mail address and you pass it to the input (e.g. `value={data.email}`), the value should be correct after the submission. You also can return an object from the action which will be passed to the `form` property. A common pattern is `value={form?.email ?? ''}`.  Please see the [form action docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions), there is a lot of detail there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll have to read the document carefully
Have a nice day!